# JQuery form submit not submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a form programmatically and trying to submit it. The submit() function does nothing, though.

```
$(".deleteLink").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $("<form></form>");
    form.attr("method", "POST");
    form.attr("action", "http://myurl.com");

    form.submit(function() {
        alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
        return false;
    });
});
```

When I set breakpoints in Firebug, I see that the click() function gets invoked and the "form" variable gets populated correctly. Everything works right up to the submit() method. The alert() method inside the submit handler never gets called.

Code inside jquery.js does execute when submit() is called, but I had a hard time tracing through it to see what it does.

I have confirmed that there is no other object named "submit" on the page.

Anyone have a clue what's happening?

**Clarification**: calling submit() without the function() parameter also does nothing.

**Further clarification**: calling submit(function(){alert()}) followed by submit() does invoke the alert(), but the form still isn't getting submitted.

**Yet another clarification**: I want the entire page to refresh. I'm not trying to do an ajax submit.

Comment: do a `form.trigger('submit');` for the actual submission

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You want to submit the form/ You want to call a JS first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must inject the new form into the document before submitting:

```
$("body").append(form);
form.submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching submit event handler instead of calling submit on form object, use this

```
form.submit();
```

*You code would be*

```
$(".deleteLink").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $("<form></form>");
    form.attr("method", "POST");
    form.attr("action", "http://myurl.com");

    form.submit(function() {
        alert('Handler for .submit() called.');       
    });
    form.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

call `form.submit()` to trigger to submit form

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$(".deleteLink").click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $.post(    
        'http://myurl.com',
        function(){
            alert('success');
            // window.location.href = 'other page';
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: I think this does an ajax submit(). I want to refresh the whole page.

Comment: window.location.href = 'other page'; will do the job